# Error when using tf.saved_model.simple_save()

Tags: python, tensorflow, server, keras

I am trying host an image classification model on my machine, i was trying to implement the steps given in this article [Medium serving ml models](https://medium.com/tensorflow/training-and-serving-ml-models-with-tf-keras-fd975cc0fa27)

The code snippet i used is :

```
import tensorflow as tf


# The export path contains the name and the version of the model
tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(0) # Ignore dropout at inference
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model_new.hdf5')
export_path = './model/1'

# Fetch the Keras session and save the model
# The signature definition is defined by the input and output tensors
# And stored with the default serving key
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
       sess,
       export_path,
       inputs={'input_image': model.input},
       outputs={t.name:t for t in model.outputs})
```

as given in the article above. My model is stored in model_new.hdf5 file, but I am getting the following error message.

> NameError: name 'tf' is not defined

in the line

> model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model_new.hdf5')

is this the right way to use tf.saved_model.simple_save() ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error with loading your model, not with `tf.saved_model.simple_save()`. When you load a Keras model, you need to handle custom objects or custom layers. You can do this by passing a `custom_objects` dict that contains `tf` in your case:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = keras.models.load_model('model_new.hdf5', custom_objects={'tf': tf})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i am getting a new error  RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session. in the same line.

Comment: It can be a problem if you have run the code multiple times. Try calling `K.clear_session()` at the beginning.

Comment: K.clear_session() didn't work gave the same error, in my model i am using ctc layer and it is saved hdf5 file. can there be a problem because of that?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Do you have a minimal reproducible code example that I can try out?